# How to publish open graph object containing Javascript on Facebook?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Does anyone have any ideas of how https://stipple.com/ publish interactive images on Facebook? It seem's that their open graph object is defined in JSON and contains an embed code node that content Javascript. Here is the source I retreive :

```
{"id":4179463,"created_at":"2012/08/29 04:59:01 +0000","category":null,"copyright_holder_id":null,"copyright_holder_type":null,"image_url_small":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.stippleit.com/photos/4179463/small/BMW-Zagato-Roadster-concept-214-626x382.jpg?1346216340","image_url_grid":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.stippleit.com/photos/4179463/grid/BMW-Zagato-Roadster-concept-214-626x382.jpg?1346216340","image_url_large":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.stippleit.com/photos/4179463/large/BMW-Zagato-Roadster-concept-214-626x382.jpg?1346216340","image_url_extra_large":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.stippleit.com/photos/4179463/extra_large/BMW-Zagato-Roadster-concept-214-626x382.jpg?1346216340","image_height":382,"image_width":626,"metadata_date":null,"detail_url":"http://stipple.com/photos/4179463","embed_code":"<img width=\"626\" height=\"382\" src=\"https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.stippleit.com/photos/4179463/original/BMW-Zagato-Roadster-concept-214-626x382.jpg?1346216340\" alt=\"stippled-photo\" data-stipple-photo-id=\"4179463\" />\n<script type=\"text/javascript\" async src=\"https://stipple.com/embed/4179463.js\"></script>\n","prototype":false,"headline":null,"abstract":null,"image_object_name":null,"city":null,"credit":null,"taken_at":null,"copyright_notice":null,"source_page":"http://blog.caranddriver.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/BMW-Zagato-Roadster-concept-214-626x382.jpg","iso":null,"focal_length":null,"aperture":null,"shutter_speed":null,"prototype_image_id":null,"photo_copy_group_id":null,"url":"http://blog.caranddriver.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/BMW-Zagato-Roadster-concept-214-626x382.jpg","caption":"","linked_caption":"","is_snaffled":true,"is_claimed":false,"is_photo_admin":null,"liked_by_current_user":false,"like_count":3,"reposted_by_current_user":false,"repost_count":0,"copyright_holder":null,"tagger":{"id":6380,"friendly_id":"auto","name":"Auto","avatar_url":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/stipple-avatars-production/users/6380/thumbnail/audi-rs8.jpg?1346351483","is_followed":null},"captioner":null,"photosets":[],"photosets_count":0,"likes":[{"id":2073,"name":"FailHarder","avatar_url":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/stipple-avatars-production/users/2073/thumbnail/DSC_0102_900px.jpg?1336524823"},{"id":6784,"name":"Daman","avatar_url":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/stipple-avatars-production/users/6784/thumbnail/IMG_20120805_152945.jpeg?1344641242"},{"id":6380,"name":"Auto","avatar_url":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/stipple-avatars-production/users/6380/thumbnail/audi-rs8.jpg?1346351483"}],"likes_count":3,"comments":{"models":[{"id":"80ed3086-4ae3-11e2-9744-b2c7ad5767bd:Photo-4179463","body":"It ain't easy to make a roadster this ugly.  Hats off to the team at BMW.","created_at":"2012/12/20 20:26:15 +0000","user_id":11347,"avatar_url":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/stipple-avatars-production/users/11347/thumbnail/delay-mugshot_normal.jpg?1355852303","name":"Grumpy Bastard","profile_url":"https://stipple.com/a#browse/user/11347","created_at_display":"December 20, 2012","linked_body":"It ain't easy to make a roadster this ugly.  Hats off to the team at BMW."}],"last_seen":"80ed3086-4ae3-11e2-9744-b2c7ad5767bd:Photo-4179463","per_page":10},"filter_user_id":"auto"}
```

Thanks.